# Get HTTP request twice when access server by Chrome browser

Tags: netty

I am looking io.netty.example.http.helloworld example. And I got http request twice in "messageReceived" when I accessed server by Chrome browser. Does anyone know about this?

Here's my piple:

```
p.addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
p.addLast("handler", new MyHttpHandler());
```

Here's MyHttpHandler :

```
public class MyHttpHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest>{
    @Override
        protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest request) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("Get the request->" + request.toString());
            }
}
```

I always got "Get the request->......." twice.

Comment: Is this consistent for all browsers? I believe Chrome will pre-fetch a page before you hit enter and then do it again when you hit enter. See: http://superuser.com/questions/394562/can-i-turn-off-google-chromes-new-prerendering

Comment: Thanks for your help. yes, this only happen when using Chrome. I will try to turn-off prefetching and retest.